# Trying to transfer mysql database data to javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, database

I have tried few things bet they don't seem to work, my code works fine if I populate the array myself without database therefore the problem is with retrieving data from database.

```
var countries = <?php
require('connection.php');
$query = 'SELECT product_name FROM products';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
while($products = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)){
    echo json_encode($products);
//OR
//$products = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
//echo json_encode($products);
}
 ?>;
```

This is the code I have tried but it is not working 
I am sending countries to a function

```
autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
```

In this function I am parsing through the array in such a way

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    /*check if the item starts with the same letters as the text field value:*/
    /*here arr is the array 'countries' send to the function autocomplete*/
    if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {//code snippet
   }}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are `echo`ing a JSON string at each iteration of the `while()` loop. So, it will writes a non-valid JSON string. You could create an array, populate it, and finally, write it as JSON:

```
<?php
require('connection.php');
$query = 'SELECT product_name FROM products';
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$products = []; // new array
while($product = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
    $products[] = $product ; // push into array
}
// finally, write JSON:
?>
var countries = <?php echo json_encode($products) ?>;
```

Comment: I have already tried this too because this solution was given in the answer of an another question at stackoverflow. Is there any other way of doing this?

Comment: @Anonymous Please, what's the problem you're facing with this? What is the given error? Could you please show the output? Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to send an array to a function which will parse through the array and apply autocomplete to the textfield. I have now realized that I have been parsing the array as an numeric array but maybe  I am getting an associative array in "countries" I am updating the Question, maybe that will help in understanding what I am trying to achieve

Comment: @Anonymous Ok, I see. Could you please add a little part of your array? Thank you.

Comment: var countries = ["Santana Gamma - Syrah","Santana Axel - Black","Canon EOS 5D Mark IV","Sony Alpha99 II","Nikon D3300","Pentax K-1","microSD Card","Canon EOS 77D"];  //this is the kind of array I am trying to get from the database and if I explicitly define it then the code is working fine

Comment: @Anonymous So `arr[i]` should contains `"Santana Gamma - Syrah"`, and so on. What is your error with your JavaScript?

Comment: No errors. No suggestions are being shown. I am using sublime Text therefore I can't even do debugging